# Crop the image with 4 different corner radii. Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the following design. How can I implement it in Flutter? I tried using a stack with the image at the bottom and a frame on top using a .png, but I don't think that's the best solution. Is there a better approach?

[image]

Comment: provide your code that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

the appropriate approach would be to apply a [`CustomClipper`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html).

Here is an article to explain the topic : https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-custom-clipper-28c6d380fdd6

So you have to create your custom class that extends the CustomClipper.

Example (that doesn't suit your case) :

```
class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0.0, size.width - 20.0, 0.0)
      ..lineTo(40.0, 70.0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(10.0, 85.0, 0.0, 120.0)
      ..close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

This code comes from the [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) (you can find some cool example in here).

Then you can use it on your image as follow :

```
 ClipPath(
        clipper: MyCustomClipper(),
        child: MyImageWidget(),
        ),
      )
```

Now all you have to do is discover the possibility of CustomClipper and create the class that match your case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that, you must use a CustomClipper, check this code

```dart
class ImageClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double radius;

  ImageClipper({
    this.radius = 80,
  });

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final leftHeight = size.height * 0.9;

    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0.0, radius)
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height - radius)
      // Bottom Left
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
        0.0,
        size.height,
        radius,
        size.height,
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width - radius, leftHeight)
      // Bottom Right
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width,
        leftHeight - 4,
        size.width,
        leftHeight - radius,
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0 + radius)
      // Top Right
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width,
        0.0,
        size.width - radius,
        0.0,
      )
      ..lineTo(0.0 + radius, 0.0)
      // Top Left
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        radius,
      )
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

and here is an example of how to use it

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const imageUrl =
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/268533/pexels-photo-268533.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500';

class TempPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TempPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Image clipped'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Image.network(
            imageUrl,
            height: 300,
            width: 200,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
          ClipPath(
            clipper: ImageClipper(
              radius: 20,
            ),
            child: Image.network(
              imageUrl,
              height: 300,
              width: 200,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

remember to change `shouldReclip` to false if needed